# Retrieving gpg key timed out when adding Elmer CSC PPA

Tags: apt, repository, gnupg

I'm trying to install the Elmer csc software on Ubuntu 18.04, and I pasted the command line exactly as it is from their site:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:elmer-csc-ubuntu/elmer-csc-ppa
```

I get the following:

```
Archive for the monolithic Elmer FEM software ubuntu packages.

More info: https://launchpad.net/~elmer-csc-ubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/elmer-csc-ppa

Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Error: retrieving gpg key timed out.

^C
```

I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> every time.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: You haven't told us your release of Ubuntu, but is it supported?  A quick scan shows it [ppa] doesn't support all (current supported) releases of Ubuntu; but being a 3rd party personal-archive the owner can choose what they support (ie. it's up to you to confirm you trust it, it supports your system & is maintained properly).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to do what you said.

Comment: I used the URL from your paste and went to https://launchpad.net/~elmer-csc-ubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/elmer-csc-ppa.  As I already stated, because you didn't tell us your release of Ubuntu I can't check if your release is supported (ie. *if you want us to check or help, it's information we need from you*) - but from the URL I can see it supports zesty, xenial, wily, vivid, utopic ... (many of which are EOL) but none of that is useful to me as I don't know what release of Ubuntu you are using.  If it doesn't provide support for your unspecified release of Ubuntu you shouldn't be adding it.

Comment: @Iglesias_art seems to be networking issue. Try again with the same ISP, or temporarily connect via other ISP (mobile 3G/4G internet or something similar).